# Partition being mounted as read only after copy operations despite healthy disks

Tags: kernel, lvm, hard-disk, smartctl

I have an ext3 partition that is made from a logical volume. The volume group (8 TB) is made of 3 PVs (1* 4TB, 2* 2TB). The ext3 partition is the only partition from this volume group.

I mount this partition in a folder (/plex_media/) using fstab on Manjaro linux. Everything starts and loads up as it should. However, when I start to copy things all of a sudden the partition seems to be remounted as read-only. I can see this in dmesg (output pasted below), but I am not experienced enough with dmesg to interpret the messages.

All disks have SMART enabled and there are no errors showing (displayed below). I have deleted the journal and rewritten it using tunef2s and e2fsck. I have a feeling like it could be a cable issue due to all the SATA link down messages in dmesg, but I really don't know what they mean and didn't understand online explanations.

I am at my wit's end. I can't see what could be wrong with the setup. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Fstab:

```
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=d031b8a8-f4f3-46ab-8ed6-7586a561f095 /boot          ext4    defaults,noatime  0 2
UUID=ce292a75-d067-4caa-9b6f-41658aa8acbb swap           swap    defaults,noatime  0 2
UUID=153b1d1e-97cb-4157-a5f8-16ea46309adc /              ext4    defaults,noatime  0 1
UUID=7e967bc5-29ab-45ae-b0ff-e73d97874cfe /home          ext4    defaults,noatime  0 2
#/dev/plex_media/plex_media                /plex_media    ext3    defaults,noatime  0 0
```

Dmesg output

```
[ 1645.470175] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/33
[ 1646.598486] ata5.00: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[ 1646.598498] ata5.01: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
[ 1646.603513] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/33
[ 1647.588479] ata5.00: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[ 1647.588490] ata5.01: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
[ 1647.593590] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/33
[ 1648.568480] ata5.00: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[ 1648.568492] ata5.01: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
[ 1648.573498] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/33
[ 1649.561814] ata5.00: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[ 1649.561827] ata5.01: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
[ 1649.566849] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/33
[ 1650.565192] ata5.00: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[ 1650.565204] ata5.01: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
[ 1650.570360] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/33
[ 1651.551809] ata5.00: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[ 1651.551820] ata5.01: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
[ 1651.556823] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/33
[ 1651.556982] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1651.556986] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] 
[ 1651.556989] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Scsi parity error
[ 1651.556994] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 07 7a 7a a0 00 00 01 30 00 00
[ 1651.556997] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 125467296
[ 1651.557134] Aborting journal on device dm-0-8.
[ 1651.566969] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_journal_check_start:61: Detected aborted journal
[ 1651.566972] EXT4-fs (dm-0): Remounting filesystem read-only
[ 1651.574177] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0) in ext4_free_blocks:4942: Journal has aborted
[ 1651.578693] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_journal_check_start:61: Detected aborted journal
[ 1651.578707] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0) in ext4_write_begin:1339: IO failure
[ 1651.583843] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0) in ext4_free_blocks:4942: Journal has aborted
[ 1651.588547] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_journal_check_start:61: Detected aborted journal
[ 1651.588551] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0) in ext4_free_blocks:4942: Journal has aborted
[ 1652.885140] ata5.00: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[ 1652.885152] ata5.01: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
[ 1652.890145] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/33
[ 1681.611201] EXT4-fs (dm-0): pa 0000000098646a44: logic 24576, phys. 991498240, len 2048
[ 1681.611206] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_mb_release_inode_pa:3835: group 30258, free 1962, pa_free 1963
[ 1681.611247] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): mb_free_blocks:1452: group 30258, inode 184205374: block 991500758:freeing already freed block (bit 6614); block bitmap corrupt.
[ 1681.611260] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:744: group 30258, block bitmap and bg descriptor inconsistent: 19796 vs 19797 free clusters
[ 1681.611265] EXT4-fs (dm-0): pa 000000005320a0a3: logic 18432, phys. 991500288, len 2048
[ 1681.611267] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_mb_release_inode_pa:3835: group 30258, free 1963, pa_free 1962
[ 1681.611412] EXT4-fs (dm-0): pa 00000000215c728f: logic 10240, phys. 991510528, len 2048
[ 1681.611414] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_mb_release_inode_pa:3835: group 30258, free 2048, pa_free 2047
[ 1682.748458] ata5.00: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[ 1682.748470] ata5.01: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
[ 1682.753459] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/33
[ 1684.048464] ata5.00: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[ 1684.048475] ata5.01: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
[ 1684.055559] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/33
```

SMART output

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdc
[sudo] password for aelsayed: 
smartctl 7.0 2018-12-30 r4883 [x86_64-linux-4.19.60-1-MANJARO] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-18, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Caviar Green (AF)
Device Model:     WDC WD20EARS-00MVWB0
Serial Number:    WD-WCAZA0851330
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 25a4aa68c
Firmware Version: 51.0AB51
User Capacity:    2.000.398.934.016 bytes [2,00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Tue Aug 13 12:17:14 2019 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x02) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (39180) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 378) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x3035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   198   195   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       997
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   167   158   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       6625
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   091   091   000    Old_age   Always       -       9853
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   071   071   000    Old_age   Always       -       21198
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       5153
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       379
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   143   143   000    Old_age   Always       -       171431
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   113   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       37
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       28

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.0 2018-12-30 r4883 [x86_64-linux-4.19.60-1-MANJARO] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-18, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Caviar Green (AF)
Device Model:     WDC WD20EARS-00MVWB0
Serial Number:    WD-WMAZA0280349
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 60041fdb1
Firmware Version: 50.0AB50
User Capacity:    2.000.398.934.016 bytes [2,00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Tue Aug 13 12:17:17 2019 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x02) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (37200) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 424) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x3035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   166   159   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       6691
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   091   091   000    Old_age   Always       -       9224
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   072   072   000    Old_age   Always       -       21032
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       5060
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       368
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   170   170   000    Old_age   Always       -       91513
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   113   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       37
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       27
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 7.0 2018-12-30 r4883 [x86_64-linux-4.19.60-1-MANJARO] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-18, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Blue
Device Model:     WDC WD40EZRZ-00GXCB0
Serial Number:    WD-WCC7K6ZKKS6P
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 2bb9a65bf
Firmware Version: 80.00A80
User Capacity:    4.000.787.030.016 bytes [4,00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Aug 13 12:17:19 2019 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x80) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (43680) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 463) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x3035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   209   169   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       4550
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       25
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1064
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       25
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       21
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   184   184   000    Old_age   Always       -       49880
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   114   102   000    Old_age   Always       -       36
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   198   110   000    Old_age   Always       -       156166
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this error. It turns out that SATA port number 5 was not working. I simply swapped to another port and it now runs fine. No dmesg messages about the SATA link being down. Hard disk was marked as having errors due to being remounted as read only, so had to run a fsck which turned back no errors!